# How do I read a list of values from a file in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file-handling

I have a list of values from a file in this format:

```
#number of items#
#item type#value x#value y#
#...
```

example:

```
#100#
#1#150#200#
#1#250#200#
#2#350#200#
#2#450#250#
#1#550#350#
#...
```

Would like to read this into the code...

Comment: Right now I have the list hardwired in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, don't know about performance though

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSArray *lines = [fileContent componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

if (lines.count > 1)
{
    NSString *firstLine = [lines objectAtIndex:0];
    NSCharacterSet *seperatorSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"];

    int itemCount = [[firstLine stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:seperatorSet] intValue];

    for (int i = 1; i < lines.count; ++i)
    {
        NSString *line = [lines objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray  *components = [line componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:seperatorSet];

        //starts at 1 because first and last are empty strings
        int type = [[components objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
        int x    = [[components objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
        int y    = [[components objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look on NSScanner : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html